# The verb "to creak" and prepositions

Tags: word-meaning

What variants are correct:

1. She creaks a chair when sit in it
2. She creaks with a chair when sit in it
3. A old chair creaks with an irritating sound

Comment: The chair creaks. If a person creaks, she is old and has brittle bones. But a person cannot creak something. This is easily found in online dictionaries, which you might check before asking.

Answer (score 3):

The verb **creak** is intransitive. It means to *emit* a particular kind of sound.

The piglet squeals.

We do not **squeal** the piglet. (ungrammatical)

She can **make the chair creak** when she sits in it.

But she does not "creak the chair".  There is no transitive verb **creak** which means "to cause something to emit a (creaky) noise".

Comment: In the example, `A old chair creaks with an irritating sound` would be correct

Comment: Yes, the chair creaks.

Comment: And, can we say: "She often likes to rustle with leaves when just fools outdoors in autumn" ?

Comment: Close.  We wouldn't  say **with** leaves but would say rather **rustle through the leaves** or **rustle in the leaves** when **just fooling around outdoors**.